# Classification and regression trees: what is a sensible value for the minimum number of observations in terminal nodes

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

Here I'll borrow some parameter names from the R `rpart` package for illustration.

The most important hyperparameter for pruning a CART tree is the cost-complexity parameter (i.e., `cp`). However, there are other parameters that affect the size of the tree, such as (1) the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node in order for a split to be attempted (i.e., `minsplit`); (2) the minimum number of observations in terminal nodes (i.e., `minbucket`).

Now I know that `cp` is the fundamental driver for over/under-fitting, but I also think there must be some circumstances where I need to pay attention to `minsplit` or `minbucket`.

So my question is, when should I consider changing the default value of `minbucket` (or `minsplit`)? In addition, how do I determine a sensible value for the parameter?